# best way of search items of list in another list python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance, search

I have a list with 32683 of length and i have to search items of this list in another list with 2905 of length that i wrote it like this:

```
for item in phone_register_users:
    if item not in service_users_ids:
       counter += 1
```

(length of phone_register_users is 32683 and service_users_ids is 2905)
but it takes about 14 seconds to complete it and this is too much, how can i improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use set:

```
set1 = set(phone_user_register_list1)
set2 = set(services_user_ids_list2)
unq = set1.intersection(set2)
```

from the intersection you can get the list of elements which in phone user register and service users id both.

So to do the counter of element which are in phone register but not in services user id use:

```
counter = len(phone_register_user)-len(unq)
```

Comment: This answer is the best when each list has a huge amount of duplicate values, if ids in each list are unique, the intersection would take `O(N*M)` which is not really good.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), the complexity for `list` to search is `O(n)`, you can try using a `set` or `dict` to reduct it to `O(1)`, something like this should be enough:

```
service_users_ids = [...]
phone_register_users = [...]
service_users_ids_set = set(service_users_ids)
for item in phone_register_users:
    if item not in service_users_ids_set:
        counter += 1
```

Comment: convert both lists to the sets and calculate intersection -- that's much faster than manual counting